# This is likely a mistake, as Provider will not automatically update dependents

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

whenever I add the provider to the MultipleProvider it just shows this weird error not not able to solve it after spending 4 hours.

**main.dart**

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<HandleImageSelectionModel>(
            create: (_) => HandleImageSelectionModel()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Provider class**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class HandleImageSelectionModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isSelectionModeEnabled = false;
  HandleImageSelectionModel();
  toggleSelectionMode() {
    isSelectionModeEnabled = !isSelectionModeEnabled;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Changing State**

```
Provider.of<HandleImageSelectionModel>(context)
                  .toggleSelectionMode();
```

**Trying to consume here**

```
Consumer<HandleImageSelectionModel>(
                    builder: (context, isEnabled, child) {
                      print(isEnabled);

                      return Positioned(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: CircularCheckBox(
                              value: true,
                              materialTapTargetSize:
                                  MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                              onChanged: (bool x) {}),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `Provider` when the class you pass is a `ChangeNotifier`.

Use `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<HandleImageSelectionModel>
```